# Formatting TimeField

Tags: django, timefield

I'm overriding my model admin form in order to change the format of the displayed time of a `TimeField` field:

```
class myTimeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start_time = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.TimeInput(format='%H:%M'))
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = myTimeForm
```

Now, the `now` and the clock button I had with the default form have disappeared (in the screenshot below `Start time` is with the overridden widget, `End time` with the default one.

[image]

What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Django admin uses the `AdminTimeWidget` instead of `forms.TimeInput`. Try changing your code to the following:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminTimeWidget

class myTimeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start_time = forms.TimeField(widget=AdminTimeWidget(format='%H:%M'))
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Comment: No, `AdminTimeWidget` is not currently documented. You can see that it's the default widget for `models.TimeField` in the Django admin by looking at [the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ff05de760cc4ef4c7f188e163c722ec3bc1f0cbf/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L78).

Comment: gotcha .. Thanks. Apparently, setting the format is not working :(. Tried it with every combination. placed in __init__ to override the field widget also. Still, not working.

Comment: That's not enough information for anyone to help you. It would be better to ask a new question rather than commenting on a 5-year old question.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, will do :). For starters, I just used the exactly similar pattern written above and register it to admin like `admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)` and it's not detecting the format parameter value while showing in the admin page.

Comment: I just tested the above code in Django 1.11 and it still works for me.

Comment: I just tested the whole flow, the problem is that while creating/setting the value first time using `now` or `clock` button, it is showing in the default format. After saving and refreshing - it is showing it in the desired passed format :). I should have tested the whole flow. I think I can live with this for now. I hope you get what I am saying. BTW, Thanks for help.

Comment: Since those buttons use JavaScript to populate the fields, it might be quite tricky to get them to work. You might be better to look for a different widget, rather than trying to customise the undocumented `AdminTimeWidget`.

Comment: Its not that important. I am gonna keep it that way ;). Thanks for all the help, really appreciate it. :)